# Hibernate 5 + Apache Olingo V4 + Maven Tomcat plugin= LinkageError

Tags: hibernate, odata, maven-tomcat-plugin, olingo

I want to build a little app for myself using a oracle database, Hibernate 5 and Apache Olingo V4.

I split the application in a separate Hibernate and a separate OData project both using maven.

So my Hibernate service is working. And my Odata service (with example data) is working too.

Now i want to combine these project using maven.
In the Odata projects pom I add the dependency of my hibernate project and get the following error message.

> SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with
>   path [/esa_odatav4] threw exception [java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving interface method
>   "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader)
>   of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader
>   (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the
>   method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have
>   different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used
>   in the signature] with root cause java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving interface method
>   "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader)
>   of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader
>   (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the
>   method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have
>   different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used
>   in the signature  at
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I already searched for the linked error and found a lot of stuff that didn't helped me. I tried different exclusions.

**For running the application I'm using the maven tomcat plugin what didn't work. The weird thing is if I run the project with a local tomcat instance it runs perfectly.**

Has someone a clue how to run the application on the maven plugin?

But I'm almost sure that the error have to do with the libraries of the projects. I've no more clue.

My Hibernate project dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And my OData dependencies are:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>odata-server-api</artifactId>
        <version>${odata.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>odata-server-core</artifactId>
        <version>${odata.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>odata-commons-api</artifactId>
        <version>${odata.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>odata-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>${odata.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 <properties>
    <javax.version>2.5</javax.version>
    <odata.version>4.3.0</odata.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```